# Using Java functional API with Spring Cloud Data Flow and Polled Consumers

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-stream

I am working on a project that is trying to use the polled consumer API. However, [existing documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#spring-cloud-streams-overview-using-polled-consumers), [blog posts](https://spring.io/blog/2018/02/27/spring-cloud-stream-2-0-polled-consumers) and [sample code](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/blob/main/processor-samples/polled-consumer/src/main/java/demo/PolledConsumerApplication.java) seems to use deprecated annotations (such as `org.springframework.cloud.stream.annotation.Input`). This seems to be because they are relying on the older style of Spring Cloud stream applications rather than using Java functional api (e.g., `java.util.function.Function`), as shown in other examples such as [this one](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/main/processor-samples/uppercase-transformer), given in the same repo.

Is there a way to use functional style with polled consumers in Spring Cloud Stream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using outdated documentation. The most current is available from the project site - https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud-stream#learn.

The section you are looking for is - https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.1.5/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#spring-cloud-streams-overview-using-polled-consumers

Comment: It looks like this should be roughly the same - my link (https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#spring-cloud-streams-overview-using-polled-consumers) points to `current` whereas yours points to `3.1.5`. Is the link in your answer really more up to date?

Also, more importantly, I'm looking at those docs and don't see a clear path forward for implementing the functional programming API either (forgive my ignorance, still learning how to use the functional programming API in general).

Comment: I am not sure I follow. I gave you the link for polled consumers with functional programming model. Isn't that what you are asking?

Comment: Ah, my bad, I see it now. Sorry, at first glance didn't notice the differences, but now I see that 3.1.5 docs aren't using @Input and @Output annotations, and instruct you to use `spring.cloud.stream.pollable-source` property. Great, thanks